# How to recover the deadlock error in golang?

Tags: error-handling, go

I wanna catch the deadlock error.
But the code does not work.
Is it possiable to recover deadlock in golang?
Maybe I just missed something fundamental.
Please give me a clue.

```
func neverDoneUnlessAllOver() {
    defer func() {
        fmt.Println("-------------------------------")
        if err := recover(); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }()

    select {}
}
```

Comment: There is no way to recover from a deadlock panic. The panic occurs in the runtime and user code can't catch it.

Comment: @Stephen Winberg I see, there is no way to recover from a deadlock panic.

Comment: @squint Seems it's a duplicate.

Comment: Note: a deadlock is not a panic. It's a fatal error. Hence not recoverable through defer.

Comment: @StephenWeinberg why not make your comment an answer?